# Where is my ClamAV log?

Tags: security, ubuntu, logging, cron, antivirus

I use this code to run a daily check through cron

```
30 01 * * * /usr/bin/freshclam --quiet; /usr/bin/clamscan --recursive --no-summary --infected / 2>/dev/null
```

I'm not sure if this code stores a log file at all.

I want to know:
If it does, then where can I find it? 
If it doesn't what is required to be changed to store the logs?

Answer (score 14):

From [AskUbuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19699/how-to-view-results-of-last-clamscan-scan):

There is no log file by default - the output goes to stdout.

In order to have a log specify it with the `-l` option i.e. `-l clamav.log`